# Java 8 serialization exception Exception after upgrading to springboot 2.5.6

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm getting `java.io.UncheckedIOException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type` java.time.LocalDateTime `not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling` when I upgraded to sprngboot 2.5.6. I tried several solutions from online but doesn't see to work for me. Added the below dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Have the below custom object mapper but disabling it doesn't work either

```
 @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {

        return new ObjectMapper()
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
                .registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule())
                .enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE)
                .findAndRegisterModules();
```

Comment: Ditch the dependencies, ditch your `ObjectMapper` and add `spring-boot-starter-json` that will add the required modules. Adding a dependency with scope `provided` will not make it available at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this using `ZonedDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime`.